# 'net use' command returns nothing when called by subprocess.

Tags: python

I'm running a daemon as a service on a Windows server that's meant to listen to triggers and create folders on a server. However I ran into difficulty with the fact that though the command prompt recognise my 'Y:' drive mapping, the service does not.

Looking into it, I was advised that the issue was likely that the mapping was not universally set up. So I tried to get the service to run the `net use` command and map the same drive at that level of access.

Note: The daemon uses `logger.info` to write to a text file.

```
command = ['net', 'use','Y', '\\\\REAL.IP.ADDRESS\\FOLDER',
            '/user:USER', 'password']
response = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = response.communicate()
logger.info("net use result:")
logger.info(result[0])
logger.info(result[1])

command = ['net', 'use',]
response = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = response.communicate()
logger.info("Current drives:")
logger.info(result[0])
logger.info(result[1])
```

However when running that I got no response at all from the process, and then a response telling me that there are no current drives.

```
INFO - net use result:
INFO - 
INFO - None
INFO - Current drives:
INFO - New connections will be remembered.  There are no entries in the list.  
INFO - None
```

Maybe I'm dumb but shouldn't it return something in response, especially if it's failing to execute the command? Or am I actually not able to map drives at this level?

Note: The daemon's logger module prepends every line with `INFO -` so for the purpose of this question you can ignore that.

Comment: Persistent drive mappings are only restored on an interactive logon, which services typically don't perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, services run under the `Local System` account and cannot access network resources. If you want to be able to access your network from a service, try running the service as a user with network privileges. (Note that this may be a security concern!)

In the `Services` panel, go to the `Properties` of your service and click the `Log On` tab. Select `This account` and specify the user credentials.